Exporting Godot 4.2.2 project to Xcode, when building project in Xcode it gives error: Undefined symbol: _main
My Godot project runs fine, and I can successfully export the project to Xcode. When I try to build it in Xcode it gives me the error "Undefined symbol: _main". I did this a while ago and my project worked in Xcode, and I don't know what changed to it.
Extra info:
Godot version 4.2.2
Using a MacBook Pro with an i5pProcessor
I'm not sure what else to give for this problem so if someone needs more info to help me then please ask for it.
I tried multiple times to re-export it, and one time I got it to build, but it wouldn't run and seconds later when I re-built it, it failed again.
